# Can't add data to TableView if controller is specified in FXML. Can't bind `onAction` if controller is NOT specified

Tags: javafx, tableview, mouseevent, fxml

I am learning JavaFX FXML. In order to add data to `TableView` I add controller to `FXMLLoader` in a POJO class.

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/views/my_view.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setController(controller);

        try {
            VBox myView = fxmlLoader.load();    
             controller.getInboxTable().setItems(getMyDisplayedItems());
             //...
```

Root of FXML file has this definition:

```xml
<VBox fx:id="rootVBox" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
```

Thus, I can't specify controller in FXML file.

When I define Buttons in the same class I can't specify `onMouseClicked` because "No controller specified for top level element".

So, I can either populate `TableView` with data or attach action handler, but not both. What is the correct way to attach `SortedList` to TableView AND specify onAction in FXML?

Comment: Works fine for me. Why do you think your approach would fail????

Comment: @fabian Which approach? (1) Specify controller in FXML and fail to attach data to TableView or (2) Don't specify controller in FXML and fail to bind #onMouseClicked in FXML?

Comment: Either approach (specifying the controller class in FXML or setting the controller directly with code) will work, and either will allow you to both specify handler functions in FXML and call methods on the controller (e.g. to set the data). It's not really clear what the issue is. Can you post a complete example and the stack trace from the exception?

Comment: @James_D How to bind data to TableView if Controller is specified in FXML? I can't find syntax for `TableViewdata="MyList"` statement. Likewise, if I don't bind controller I can't specify on mouse click in FXML.

Comment: Just get the controller from the `FXMLLoader` and call the same method you are currently calling. (Or, as I said, do what you are currently doing. It should work fine and you should be able to specify event handlers. If you won't post code and the exception, there's not much that can be done to help.)

Comment: I was writing about the approach you posted, i.e. creating the controller instance yourself, not adding the `fx:controller` attribute in the but adding the `onMouseClicked="#myHandlerMethod"` attributes to some nodes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use FXML, try to manage all the View layer's code there. You can add the controller in the FXML file via the `fx:controller` tag. Have a look at the [Creating an Address Book with FXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm) at Oracle Docs. Most of the code below is from that tutorial. 
Another thing is that using such a way of assigning the controller should fix the "No controller specified for top level element" issue. I added a button which causes the Table View's data is shuffled.

So, assuming you have all the files in the folder called `sample` in your project folder:

Main.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(final Stage stage) {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("/sample/sample.fxml"));
    try {
      Parent root;
      root = fxmlLoader.load();
      Scene scene = new Scene(root);
      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
  }
}
```

sample.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory?>
<VBox fx:id="rootVBox"
      xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <Button text="Shuffle Data" onAction="#shuffleDataButtonClicked"/>
    <TableView fx:id="tableView">
        <columns>
            <TableColumn text="First Name">
                <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="firstName" />
                </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
            <TableColumn text="Last Name">
                <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="lastName" />
                </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
            <TableColumn text="Email Address">
                <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="email" />
                </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
        </columns>
    </TableView>
</VBox>
```

Controller.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Controller {
  @FXML
  private TableView<Person> tableView;

  @FXML
  private void initialize() {
    tableView.getItems().addAll(getSomePersonData());
  }

  private Vector<Person> getSomePersonData() {
    Person jacobSmith = new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com");
    Person isabellaJohnson = new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com");
    Person ethanWilliams = new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com");
    Person emmaJones = new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com");
    Person michaelBrown = new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com");

    Vector<Person> people = new Vector<>();

    people.add(jacobSmith);
    people.add(isabellaJohnson);
    people.add(ethanWilliams);
    people.add(emmaJones);
    people.add(michaelBrown);

    return people;
  }

  @FXML
  private void shuffleDataButtonClicked() {
    Collections.shuffle(tableView.getItems());
  }
}
```

Person.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Person {
  private final SimpleStringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty("");
  private final SimpleStringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty("");
  private final SimpleStringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty("");

  public Person() {
    this("", "", "");
  }

  public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
    setFirstName(firstName);
    setLastName(lastName);
    setEmail(email);
  }

  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName.get();
  }

  public void setFirstName(String fName) {
    firstName.set(fName);
  }

  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName.get();
  }

  public void setLastName(String fName) {
    lastName.set(fName);
  }

  public String getEmail() {
    return email.get();
  }

  public void setEmail(String fName) {
    email.set(fName);
  }
}
```